# How to send node.js logs to Cloudwatch Logs from Elastic Beanstalk Docker application?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

Amazon offers these readymade files for sending Tomcat/Apache/nginx logs to Cloudwatch Logs, which work great.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.cloudwatchlogs.html

However for my purposes they only send nginx logs, which isn't really sufficient and unfortunately they also provide zero documentation on the file format. What I'm trying to achieve is to send node.js logs from my Docker application to Cloudwatch (since autoscaling makes instances come and go).

So having files like `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/add839a3b599-stdouterr.log` to appear in Cloudwatch.

So, what I have tried so far is adapt the webrequests config from the link above:

```
##############################################################################
## Sends docker logs to CloudWatch Logs
##############################################################################
Mappings:
  CWLogs:
    ApplicationLogGroup:
      LogFile: "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*-stdouterr.log"
      TimestampFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

Outputs:
  ApplicationLogGroup:
    Description: "The name of the Cloudwatch Logs Log Group created for this environments web server access logs. You can specify this by setting the value for the environment variable: WebRequestCWLogGroup. Please note: if you update this value, then you will need to go and clear out the old cloudwatch logs group and delete it through Cloudwatch Logs."
    Value: { "Ref" : "AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0ApplicationLogGroup"}

Resources :
  AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0ApplicationLogGroup:    ## Must have prefix:  AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0
    Type: "AWS::Logs::LogGroup"
    DependsOn: AWSEBBeanstalkMetadata
    DeletionPolicy: Retain     ## this is required
    Properties:
      LogGroupName:
        "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
          Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
          OptionName: ApplicationLogGroup
          DefaultValue: {"Fn::Join":["-", [{ "Ref":"AWSEBEnvironmentName" }, "stdouterr"]]}
      RetentionInDays: 14

  ## Register the files/log groups for monitoring
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      "AWS::CloudFormation::Init":
        CWLogsAgentConfigSetup:
          files:
            ## any .conf file put into /tmp/cwlogs/conf.d will be added to the cwlogs config (see cwl-agent.config)
            "/tmp/cwlogs/conf.d/stdouterr.conf":
              content : |
                [stdouterr]
                file = `{"Fn::FindInMap":["CWLogs", "ApplicationLogGroup", "LogFile"]}`
                log_group_name = `{ "Ref" : "AWSEBCloudWatchLogs8832c8d3f1a54c238a40e36f31ef55a0ApplicationLogGroup" }`
                log_stream_name = {instance_id}
                datetime_format = `{"Fn::FindInMap":["CWLogs", "ApplicationLogGroup", "TimestampFormat"]}`
              mode  : "000400"
              owner : root
              group : root
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. :/

Also, does anyone have any idea if logs appear at all if fe. the timestamp format is wrong? Specially important since by default exceptions don't really have timestamps, so the actual errors would just disappear.

My application log lines currently look like this:
`2016-07-05 09:11:31 ::1 - GET / 200 (5.107 ms)`

Comment: it's a great question, and it's really absurd that amazon doesn't make this brain dead simple, or why they chose to default to the nginx or proxy logs by default in their example. Thanks for validating that I'm not crazy for wanting and expecting the same ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this link to setup cloudwatch agents on your beanstalk instances (if you haven't already) - http://serebrov.github.io/html/2015-05-20-cloudwatch-setup.html.

Next - try to send the files in /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.json to collect your docker logs. It's where the containers stdout and stderr is written to.

Comment: What do you mean? Getting logs from `/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log` would require me to know the id for the container, wouldn't it?

Comment: `LogFile: "/var/lib/docker/containers/**/*.log"` seems to work but then all the log entries in Cloudwatch are presented as json objects (`{ "log": "2016-07-05 12:17:12 10.0.1.180 - GET / 200 (0.334 ms)\n", "stream": "stdout", "time": "2016-07-05T12:17:12.134355109Z" }`), which makes the logs really hard to read. :/ Is there a way to have them as "normal" log entries?

Comment: That is a tricky one. The best way to solve this is by changing your container logging driver (docker even has a cloudwatch log driver). I tried to do it with beanstalk and haven't succeeded yet. I'm guessing there's a way but I haven't found it yet.

Comment: You know if there are other non-rotated logs that aren't JSON? I've gotten the `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/` working with `LogFile: "/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/*.log"` but I'm guessing since they are rotated, the log driver doesn't catch them all but just seems to stop working after one deploy.

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Since the files rotate but maintain the same name the log driver should keep catching all records even after rotation (minus maybe a certain small amount that gets rotated before the log driver catches it, but that should be insignificant)

Comment: In my case, it appears that cloud watch logs only gets the logs from the very first container installed on the EC2 instance.  Once I "eb deploy" again, even though I'm specifying a wildcard in my LogFile specification, it's like it's "stuck" on that original file and doesn't see others.  Any advice?

Comment: To answer my own question, I was seeing issues where only my first log file was making it to CloudWatch.  I *think* what was going on was that the log files have similar content in the first few lines and the awslogs agent thought they were just rotated log files and therefore ignored them.  I ended up finding the first unique line in the file and using the file_fingerprint_lines parameter documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html